# dim(span{x}) = rk E[xx']

Tags: linear-algebra

$x \in L_{2}^{m}$ and I have to show that $$\dim(\mathrm{span}\,\{x\}) = rk E[xx']$$

The hint is: Show that $a \in \mathbb{\mathbb R}^{1 \times m},\ ax=0 \iff aE[xx']a'=0.$

To show that the hint is true is no problem. But I can't see the connection to $\dim(\mathrm{span}\,\{x\}) = rk E[xx']$. I know that $ax=0$ implies linear dependence.